# Python transfer function parameters to a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters

just got a simple question on whether it is possible to transfer parameters required by a function to a string or other formats that can be used outside the function

E.g. `def add(a,b): return a+b`, lack of indents, sorry for the formatting.

Is it possible to transfer those parameters into a string or other format? The aimed outcomes are:

```
a=10  
b=10

str="a,b"

add(str)
```

For simple data types it can be implemented in this way:

[image: For simple data types it can be implemented in]

But considering complicated condition, like training neural networks with `Keras`, it requires configuration information such as dataset, optimizer... in various datatype and this approach is not working unfortunately.

It is weird, but in my case, if can simplify my codes for my design of library toolbox for `training deep neuron networks` such as the `model.fit()` functions.

Hope my descriptions make sense.

------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------

Sorry for the confusing descriptions. Hope this attempt can make it clear.

My question is in the context of training neural network with Keras in Python API, here is a close version about the real question:

Let's say we have one function `funcA(p1,p2=None,p3,p4=None,....)` with some optional parameters. Then we have another function `funcB(..., params)` that calls `funcA` within it and I want to do:

`def funcB(..., params):`

`funcA(params)`

Make **params** as a container for those parameters required by `funcA()`:

`p1=...`

`p2=...`

`pn=...`

then `params=[p1....pn]` and use `funcB` as `funcB(..., params)`. So that `funcA` within it can be executed through the configures passed to `funcB()` by container **params**.

If you are interested, the real case is a training script (let's say train.py) includes:

`model.fit(data,label, batch_size, epochs, verbose...)`

I wanna find an optimal epoch amount for it `outside` the script:

`for i in range(3):`

```
 run train.py #includes model.fit(params) while params can be delivered in some way.
```

But the hard part is how to transfer multiple (optional or non-optional) parameters to a single container called **params** in my case.

Comment: As it stands, this will fail because it will tell you that add expects two arguments, and you only passed one to it.  You may want to read up on [python arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), which might get you closer to where you want to be.

Comment: I'm not entire sure if I understood your question, could you explain the most you can?

Comment: @DamianLattenero Sorry for the vague description, I've updated it.

Comment: @LudwigZhou I updated my question with the new data... I hope now that is what you were looking at, it's just an example

Comment: @LudwigZhou consider looking again my edit, now all the pieces are together there, I took some time, but I was with you from the real beginning, I'm glad you found your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit for the edit question:

To achieve that, you can give a list of parameters, and call *:

```
def funcA(p1,p3,p4=None, p5= None):
  print(p1+p3)
  if p4 != None:
    print(p1+p3+p4)

def funcB(p1,p2,p3, params):
  print(p1,p2,p3)
  funcA(*params)


funcA(2,3)
funcA(2,3,5)
funcB("hi", "everythin", "OK", [2, 3])
funcB("hi", "everythin", "OK", [2, 3, 5])
```

> For the old question:

you can use eval for this case, take a look:

```
a=10  
b=10

tup = "a,b"

def add(string): 
  ...
```

And if I understood well, you call it like:

```
add(*(eval(tup)))
```

wich gives:

> 20

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Damian Lattenero is goog but if you don't want to change the code of the function, this could work :

```
a=10  
b=10

str="a,b"

add(*(eval(str)))
```

`*` will expand the `eval` of `str` and give you the result expected.

Comment: Really nice!! it's a plus one :D

Comment: If I understood the OP's task, just mapping a perfectly parseable string into local variable names will do the job, no need to bring the heavy artillery of `eval` into this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it as you describe and **kwargs is absolutely not applicable for your case, I guess you could use `locals()` and a helper function/decorator:

```
def get_args(d, s):
   arguments = s.split(",")
   return {x: d[x] for x in arguments}

a = 10
b = "hello"

def custom_function(**kwargs):
   print(kwargs)

custom_function(**get_args(locals(), "a,b"))
```

will print
`{'a': 10, 'b': 'hello'}`

Also, the function in this case could be for example

```
def custom_function(a, b):
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: Downvoting without commenting why is bad form.